# Networkx huge amount of node and edges

Tags: python, networking, graph, networkx

I have about 40.000 nodes and also about 50.000 edges.

Is there a way to get a graph for it?
Its like taking forever when im trying it.

Thanks in advance.

```
import networkx as nx

g.add_nodes_from(nodes_refactored)
g.add_edges_from(node_edges_refactored)
g.number_of_nodes() --> 44k
g.number_of_edges() --> 47k
nx.draw(g) --> nothing happens...
```

Comment: which step is taking forever? `nx.draw(g)`  would not be able to draw such a huge graph. NetworkX is for faster graph computation not for visualization.

Comment: is there a way to get all the edges to a node?
with ```g.edges``` I can print the edges which are directly connect to the node. I want to get all the nodes related to the node.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably being super slow because the amount of nodes is incredibly high. A visual is unlikely to be useful in this case anyway as there are so many nodes & edges that it'll basically just display a big black blob on the screen. Perhaps you could map subgraphs instead, or combine nodes into supernodes?